# How to import my package.json in my Angular app.module?

Tags: angular

I want to access the version property in my package.json file.
How to import my package.json in my Angular 6 app.module?

thx
Lino

Comment: Did you try just to import JSON "module"? `import { version } from '../../package.json'`

Comment: I get this error message: webpack: Compiled successfully.
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(5,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../package.json'.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79